# How to create a class object from multiples object?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to create a structure for the data. What I have is three types of items and I want to create an order object. An order object can have multiples of each type of items. There are three types at the moment. Each type has their own details (including the lists of details, inclusions, exclusions, etc.) but they are not given here. Type3 is special as it contains a list of type1 and type2 objects (type3 = special combos consisting of type1 and type2).

My structure so far in C# terms is as follows

```
class type1{ string name{get; set;}}
class type2{ string name{get; set;}}
class type3{ 
List<type1> singleItems {get; set;}
List<type2> singleItems {get; set;}
}

var order = new {tp1 = List<type1>, tp2 = List<type2>, tp3 = List<type3>};
```

Now in Javascript I am trying to do the same but not sure how to get the same structure. So far this is what I have, but don't know what goes in the brackets specially for tp3.

```
var order = {tp1:[{}],tp2:[{}],tp3:[{}]}
```

In simple words an order is collection of three lists tp1, tp2, and tp3. Where tp3 itself is a collection of tp1 and tp2.

Comment: Create an object of `type3` with non-null lists, serialize it to JSON and see what is produced.
On a side note: your class `type3` won't compile, as both properties have the same name.

Comment: Good idea, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to structure your JavaScript model as below.

```
{
  "tp1": [{
    "name": "raj"
  }, {
    "name": "Reddy"
  }],
  "tp2": [{
    "name": "stack"
  }, {
    "name": "overflow"
  }],
  "tp3": [{
    "tp1": [{
      "name": "raj"
    }, {
      "name": "Reddy"
    }],
    "tp2": [{
      "name": "stack"
    }, {
      "name": "overflow"
    }]
  }, {
    "tp1": [{
      "name": "raj"
    }, {
      "name": "Reddy"
    }],
    "tp2": [{
      "name": "stack"
    }, {
      "name": "overflow"
    }]
  }]
}
```

And the C# class objects you need to structure like below.

```
public class Orders
{
    public List<Type1> tp1 { get; set; }
    public List<Type2> tp2 { get; set; }
    public List<Type3> tp3 { get; set; }
}

public class Type1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Type2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Type3
{
    public List<Type1> tp1 { get; set; }
    public List<Type2> tp2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can **[download the sample project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/039gbl)** to see the working example of the above structure.